# Use ViewData/ViewBag or Model to pass data to the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

When I want access to a value in the view, what should I consider to determine if this property should be added to the `Model` or if it should be sent using `ViewData["MyProperty"]`

Internally, what's the difference and what are advantages of doing one over the other?

Answer (score 2):

For me the rule is pretty simple: always use view models and never use `ViewBag/ViewData`. The The advantages of using a view model are numerous:

- Strongly typed views
- Refactor friendly code
- IntelliSense friendly code
- Avoid ugly casting in the views => leads to clearer syntax